# Changing the legend position when ploting using python-ggplot

Tags: python, python-ggplot

Is it possible to change the position of the Legend when plotting using python-ggplot? For example, from left to top?

I have tried ppb1Lp+theme_bw(legend.position="top") where ppb1Lp is a ggplot object. But it gives an error:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression.

I have also done some search on Internet, but I could only find the related answer for ggplot2 on R.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I think the error you are seeing is because you used `legend.position` instead of `legend_position` (dot is special in python, but not R, so we had to replace all dots with underscores). But unfortunately legend position is AFAIK not yet implemented, sorry. Feel free to file a bug about that.